# Parsing valid parent directories with regex

Tags: regex

Given the string `a/b/c/d` which represents a fully-qualified sub-directory I would like to generate a series of strings for each step up the parent tree, i.e. `a/b/c`, `a/b` and `a`.

With regex I can do a non-greedy `/(.*?)\//` which will give me matches of `a`, `b` and `c` or a greedy `/(.*)\//` which will give me a single match of `a/b/c`. Is there a way I can get the desired results specified above in a single regex or will it inherently be unable to create two matches which eat the same characters (if that makes sense)?

Please let me know if this question is answered elsewhere... I've looked, but found nothing.

Note this question is about whether it's possible with regex. I know there are many ways outside of regex.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so I won't answer, however I don't think it's not possible without looping, it's probably much easier to just split the path and recreate it.

Comment: What language? Just split on `/`

Comment: My question is really is it possible with regex in some simple way that I'm missing. I understand the options as far as doing it programmatically. I'm new to regex and want to know its limitations here.

Comment: Its easy to do with loop than why go for regex

Comment: I've already implemented it with split and a simple loop -- I just want to understand regex better and know what it can and can't do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution building on idea in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479028/matching-both-greedy-nongreedy-and-all-others-in-between/23480662#23480662):

- reverse the string to be matched: `d/c/b/a` For instance in PHP use `strrev($string )`
- match with `(?=(/(?:\w+(?:/|$))+))`

This give you

```
/c/b/a
/b/a
/a
```

Then reverse the matches with `strrev($string )`

This give you

```
a/b/c/
a/b/
a/
```

If you had .NET not PCRE you could do matching right to left and proably come up with same.

Comment: Awesome! Although it requires programmatic intervention it is very minimal and could be done probably with other text processing tools (or perhaps a regex replace could flip a string?). This to me seems to be the closest to an answer. I will mark it as such unless someone eventually chimes in with one that is both vanilla regex and requires no programmatic-intervention OR a definitive 'no'... It seems to me really that the right answer at this point would be 'no, the best you can do is:' followed by your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Completely different answer without reversing string.

```
(?<=((?:\w+(?:/|$))+(?=\w)))
```

This matches

```
a/
a/b/
a/b/c/
```

but you have to use C# which use variable lookbehind

Comment: Too specific, if it only works with C#s regex engine... certainly no love trying that on rubular... what I would love is if someone could chime in with an answer of why it's inherently impossible without programmatic intervention or fringe regex engines, if it proves to be the case. That would be beneficial to the community...

Comment: @birchbark But its cool and no coding... may should work too with regex module in python (not re)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
/([^\/]*)\//
```

So basically it replaces your `.*?` with `[^/]*`, and it does not have to be non-greedy. Since `/` is a special character in your case, you will have to escape it, like so: `[^\/]*`.

Comment: Used with my above example this yields matches of ```a```, ```b```, ```c```. These are not fully qualified. Per my question the matches needed are ```a```, ```a/b```, ```a/b/c```.

Comment: So you want each result to overlap? Then I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It's sounding like that is the case, but I'd love someone to definitively state some principle fact about regex that negates this possibility. I know lookarounds can capture without advancing a character, but I don't have the regex-fu to figure out how in this specific case that can be advantaged.