# Matching both greedy, nongreedy and all others in between

Tags: regex, pcre

Given a string like `"/foo/bar/baz/quux"` (think of it like a path to a file on a unixy system), how could I (if at all possible) formulate a regular expression that gives me all possible paths that can be said to contain file `quux`?

In other words, upon running a regexp against the given string (`"/foo/bar/baz/quux"`), **I would like to get as results:**

- `"/foo/"`
- `"/foo/bar/"`
- `"/foo/bar/baz/"`

I've tried the following:

- `'/\/.+\//g'` - this is greedy by default, matches `"/foo/bar/baz/"`
- `'/\/.+?\//g'` - lazy version, matches `"/foo/"` and also `"/baz/"`

**P.S.:** I'm using Perl-compatible Regexps in PHP in function `preg_match()`, for that matter)

Comment: The typical expression that you're searching for is the following [`~(?=(/[^/]+.*))/[^/]+~`](http://regex101.com/r/bY4sH8) (see group 1). So to get the desired output, you would have to revert the string and then revert again. [See demo](https://eval.in/146827)

Comment: I like your code. That was a pretty clever answer. Do write an answer so I can tick you. I think anubhava's answer hardcodes 'quux' in the regexp and so I cant' generalize it.

Comment: [Bart Kiers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50476/bart-kiers) posted an awesome trick but he deleted it, I wonder why? Here's his [regex](http://regex101.com/r/fI3oX3) `(?=(/(?:\w+/)+(?=quux)))` and here's a [more dynamic one](http://regex101.com/r/rW7pQ4) `(?=(/(?:[^/]+/)+(?=[^/]+/?$)))`

Comment: I think it's returning the wrong values or maybe I made a mistake somewhere? http://regex101.com/r/qM5bC2

Comment: You need to use different delimiters, click on the most left `/` and change it to `~` for example. Otherwise you'll need to escape all `/`. Oh! And now I see that it generates a different output than the one you wanted. It explains why Bart deleted his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felipe not looking for `/foo/bar/baz, /bar/baz, /baz` but for `/foo, /foo/bar, /foo/bar/baz`

One solution building on regex idea in comments but give the right strings:

- reverse the string to be matched: `xuuq/zab/rab/oof/` For instance in PHP use `strrev($string )`
- match with `(?=((?<=/)(?:\w+/)+))`

This give you

```
zab/rab/oof/
rab/oof/
oof/
```

Then reverse the matches with `strrev($string)`

This give you

```
/foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar
/foo
```

If you had .NET not PCRE you could do matching right to left and proably come up with same.

Comment: Yes this is the same that HamZa had suggested. I think this is as close as I can get. Apparently a regexp-only solution is unavailable.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Oh I had seen his comment about Bart Kiers answer not his reverting idea comment. Yes you are right that is same idea then.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida The regex also a touch different but basically Barts idea

Answer (score 2):

This solution will not give exact output as you are expecting but still give you pretty useful result that you can post-process to get what you need:

```
$s = '/foo/bar/baz/quux';
if ( preg_match_all('~(?=((?:/[^/]+)+(?=/[^/]+$)))~', $s, $m) )
   print_r($m[0]);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG1rD9)

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /foo/bar/baz
    [1] => /bar/baz
    [2] => /baz
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if you hardcode the stopping criteria in the regexp itself I can't use it for other cases.

Comment: But didn't you mean to find all paths that have `/quux` in the path?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida: I have edited and fixed your regex101 link and updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you but your code isn't quite correct. It's returning  
`"/foo/bar/baz"`,`"/bar/baz"` and `"/baz"` according to your working demo link.

Comment: But is `/bar/baz` not a valid unix path?

Answer (score 0):

Completely different answer without reversing string.

```
(?<=((?:\w+(?:/|$))+(?=\w)))
```

This matches

```
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz/
```

but you have to use C# which use variable lookbehind not PCRE